# Relationship between voltage and distance in electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, charge, voltage

Just to clarify, I’m just now learning about physics for the first time, and ran into some confusion about how voltage works.

In electrostatics, I learned that voltage is dependent on distance based on the formula: $V = kq/r$. As I understand, this means that the voltage of a point charge decreases with distance.

What I am confused about is whether this relationship between distance and voltage exists in electrodynamics. Based on what I know, it does not. For example, would distance matter in a battery? If I made a galvanic cell and moved the cathode and anode further apart, would the voltage decrease? Additionally, how is it that power lines are able to deliver consistent voltage despite variances in distance?

Does the electrostatic formula for the voltage of a point charge or plate not apply to batteries and circuits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you are referring to:
$$V(r)=k\frac{q}{r}$$
only applies to potentials generated by a stationary point charge (or similar). A different charge configuration, or a different environment, requires a drastically different formula. There is no such thing as a simple universal equation for $V$ that is immediately applicable to all situations. (But of course an expression for $V$ can always be obtain through the [definition of electric potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential#Electrostatics)). In the case of a circuit [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) applies, while for the potential *inside of a battery* it strongly depends on what kind of battery we are considering; but anyway this last topic has more to do with engineering and chemistry than physics.

Regarding specifically the relation voltage-distance: you have to remember that circuits, power lines, ecc. take advantage of *conductors* to "carry voltage around", and this is exactly why *Ohm's law* applies.